# How to pass parameters to Workmanager DoWork method

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I want to Schedule task to be deleted from the database after 24 hours

```
public class WorkManager extends Worker {

    public WorkManager(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        return null;
    }}
```

how can i pass the Task to be deleted as a parameter to the DoWork method like so...

```
public void deleteTask(Task task){
        DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        db.deleteOne(task);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Worker` class still does not support custom object as parameters to pass in `Data`. What you can do is tweak your `deleteOne` method to delete task based on id and pass this id to be deleted to `Worker`.

```
  public static OneTimeWorkRequest create(String id) {
      Data inputData = new Data.Builder()
              .putString(TASK_ID, id)
              .build();
      return new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SampleWorker.class)
              .setInputData(inputData)
              .setInitialDelay(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
              .build();
 }

...

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    String taskId = getInputData().getString(TASK_ID);

    ...
    ...
}
```

If you still insist on passing `Task` as parameter to your `Worker` you can try

```
 public static OneTimeWorkRequest create(Task task) {
     String strTask = new Gson().toJson(task);
     Data inputData = new Data.Builder()
             .putString(TASK, strTask)
             .build();
     return new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SampleWorker.class)
             .setInputData(inputData)
             .setInitialDelay(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
             .build();
 }

 ...

 @NonNull
 @Override
 public Result doWork() {
     String strTask = getInputData().getString(TASK);
     Task task = new Gson().fromJson(strTask, Task.class);

    ...
    ...
 }
```

Add this dependency in `build.gradle` for `Gson`

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

For more information and studies check out [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work)

Comment: another approach would be to use a WorkerFactory, more details in this article by Pietro Maggi: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/customizing-workmanager-fundamentals-fdaa17c46dd2

Comment: how can i call OnetimeWorkrequest from Mainactivity?