# How to pass complex obeject to Worker class?

Tags: android

I want to pass my `ConnectivityManger` to my `Worker` class.
I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985945/how-to-pass-parameters-to-workmanager-dowork-method) but serialize it to json is not an option for me.

Is there any other way?

My app is designed to use newest api.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a `ConnectivityManager` to a `Worker` via input data? WorkManager already manages connectivity for you and WorkManager already supports [injecting manager classes into Workers](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager)

Comment: I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: And even if you do need `ConnectivityManager` in a `Worker`, the `Worker` can get one on its own. `ConnectivityManager` is a system service, and [a `Worker` can use `getApplicationContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#getApplicationContext()) to call `getSystemService()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass your `ConnectivityManager` to your `Worker` class via input data for a number of reasons:

1. WorkManager automatically handles connectivity changes when you using [`NetworkType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/NetworkType) as part of your [work constraints](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#work-constraints)
2. WorkManager allows [injecting dependencies into your Workers](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager) via Hilt
3. If you are referring to Android's [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager) (and not your own class you've created), then each Worker can already gain access to a `Context` and, with that, any system service, such as a `ConnectivityManager`.